# Can't move desktop icons on ubuntu 19.10 -- How can I re-arrange them?

Tags: desktop-icons

I've recently upgraded to 19.10 and now every time I drag an icon to another place on desktop, it goes back to it's original place.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: GNOME3 is the desktop used by Ubuntu 19.10, and the GNOME TWEAKS https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/ gives you some control of Desktop icons. Do you have GNOME TWEAKS installed?

Comment: Yes the GNOME TWEAKS is there but when I looked there is no option regarding icon arrangement

Answer (score 0):

In Pop OS 20.04 which will match Ubuntu 20.04 you need to right click on the desktop, select customize and turn off Auto-Arrange. Also, to get desktop icons to work at all, you will need to use the Nemo file manager as your desktop file manager and turn off Extensions > Desktop Icons in Gnome Tweaks.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04, I followed your sequence of clicks and I don't have the items you describes. Could you improve (with details and screenshots) your answer, specifying also for which Ubuntu version your solution is valid? Consider that Pop_OS is off-topic.

Comment: At the moment, "auto arrange" is grayed out, and devs say its not implemented

Comment: [Related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346063/349837)